# Matlab flush stdout [not `drawnow('update')`]?

Tags: matlab, stdout, flush

I'm writing Matlab code to print a diagnostic message about encountering pathological data, print out the bad data, and terminate...I want to flush stdout out before printing any of the aforementioned diagnostics. Web searching indicates that `drawnow('update')` is the standard method, but it has also been noted that it doesn't always work (something which I have confirmed).

Flushing standard out seems like an indispensable requirement for error handling.  Surely I must be missing something about how to do it.  It would be quite a doozer for there not to be a method to do this.  How do others do this reliably?

Comment: I think we'll need to see an actual example of what you're doing to fully understand the situation and what isn't working. Are you wanting to force the Command Window to display text?

Comment: I was motivated to post this question based on a minimum working example for a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272681/matlab-minimum-working-example-of-handling-exception-higher-up-in-call-stack). In that code, I converted all the `fprintf`'s to use stdout because when using stderr, I couldn't get the stdout content to flush using `drawnow('update')`.  I find myself faced with the question again when planning the code for data checking -- how to flush stdout with certainty.

Comment: Are you using MATLAB in a terminal window (`-nodesktop`)?

Comment: No.  I use the full GUI (R2015b).